# How to work on a feature branch that relies on another unmerged feature branch?

Tags: git

Here is my situation. I have `featureBranchA` in github pending a pull request which won't get merged until tomorrow or later. I started working on `featureBranchB` but I ran in to a snag. I need the changes made in `featureBranchA` in order to make `featureBranchB` work. I hate not being able to work due to waiting on someone else.

What I've done in the past is switch to `featureBranchA` and branch off that naming the branch `featureBranchA/featureBranchB`. When `featureBranchA` is merged I then submit a pull request to the newly renamed `featureBranchB`. This is not the best approach as I have to keep a list of branches that need pull requests and watch for when the "parent" branch was merged.

Another method I've used is branching `featureBranchB` off `master` and merging changes from `featureBranchA` in to it. This always messes up when I'm submitting a pull request though. The pull request for `featureBranchB` will have its commits AND `featureBranchA` commits even though `featureBranchA` has already been merged. I've also tried using rebase instead of merge but it messes up when it comes time to submit the pull request.

Any advice on this kind of work flow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Branching featureB off featureA is the best approach.  Rather than monitoring when featureA is approved, submit the pull request when you're ready and note in the request that it depends on featureA.  Reference the issue number in the pull request and Github will place notes itself.  Something like "this depends on #123 being accepted".

If featureA is changed before being accepted, you (or the person accepting the pull request) should merge or rebase with featureA prior to merging featureB.

Comment: stupid question - in this example, do you open the Pull Request for featureBranchB with the base as featureBranchA or master?

Comment: @daredadevil Since featureBranchA hasn't been accepted yet, can you open a pull request off it?

Comment: @Schwern it can be done. But is it meaningful to do so. According to GitHub documetation, the [Base (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) for creating a Pull Request is technically the branch I'd like to merge my changes into. 
Someone who reviews the PR would be confused by the commits from featureBranchA when I open  a Pull Request with the base as master. These commits aren't visible when the Base is featureBranchA. But this would mean that the PR merges my changes into branch I started from.i.e featureBranchA.
I don't really know what is the best practice here.

Comment: @daredadevil The best practice is to put at the top of the PR "*Do not merge this until featureBranchA is merged. This is here so you know what's coming next and we can discuss it.*" In that sense, I'd base the PR off featureBranchA initially. If you base off the current master you'll get artificial conflicts which aren't a help to anyone. If you base it off featureBranchA it's closer to what will really get merged and that's better for discussion. No matter what, you're going to have to rebase this PR off master *after* featureBranchA has been merged.